# Joint Probability Distribution question?

Tags: probability

$f(x,y) = 1/x$ where $x \in (1,\infty)$ and $y \in (0,1/x)$

I need to find the marginal probability density functions, $f_{X}(x)$ and $f_{Y}(y)$. For a while I thought I was on the right track. I think $f_{X}(x) = 1/x^2$ where $x \in (1, \infty)$. I had a hunch that I would need to use the inverse of $1/x$ to find $f_{Y}(y)$ but now I am unsure.

Any help you could provide would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw the curve $y=1/x$ (for positive $x$). Our joint density function is $1/x$ over the region $K$ which is below the curve $y=1/x$, above the $x$-axis, and to the right of the line $x=1$.

To find the marginal density of $X$, we "integrate out" $y$. Note that $y$ goes from $0$ to $1/x$. We have
$$\int_{y=0}^{1/x} \frac{1}{x}\,dy=\frac{1}{x^2}$$
(for $x\gt 1$). For completeness, note that the marginal density of $X$ is $0$ elsewhere.

To find the marginal density of $Y$, integrate out $x$. We get
$$\int_{x=1}^{1/y}\frac{1}{x}\,dx.$$
Integrate. We get $\ln(1/y)$, or equivalently $-\ln(y)$. Here $0\lt y\lt 1$.

Comment: Thank you so much. That makes sense, I am a bit confused though still. $ln(0)$ is $\infty$. Can we integrate the marginal density function from 0 to 1 then?

Comment: As I wrote, the (marginal) density of $y$ is $-\ln(y)$ for $0\lt y\lt 1$. The integral $\int_0^1 -\ln(y)\,dy$ is what you may recall from calculus an **improper integral**. It converges. For when we integrate $-\ln(y)$, we get $y-y\ln(y)$. To "evaluate" this at $0$, we take the limit as $y$ approaches $0$ from the right of $y-y\ln(y)$. It turns out that $y\ln(y)$ has limit $0$ as $y\to 0^+$. (Yes, the ln blows up, but $y$ approaches $0$ faster.)

Comment: You are welcome. You will find that probability gives your calculus quite a workout.

Comment: That is definitely true. So many integrals.